# loop through folders matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, directory

I need to loop through a folder (called Data) which contains many folders with different names. I need to pick out some specific folders, which each start with the same word (Variance). Then, when in these 'Variance ...' folders there are two files which I need to open and put through a function to get some information. The files have the same name for each of the folders (F_1 and F_0):

1) Loop through folder until a sub-folder with a specific start of a name is found.

2) Enter the sub_folder

3) Open the two files in there and use them for a function (I can do this bit)

4) Return up to the original folder (Data) and carry on the loop looking for the specific sub-folders, and repeat until all of the sub-folders have been found.

Comment: You can utilize [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) with a wildcard (see the documentation) but the downside is that it is not recursive. You can write your own recursive `dir` function (not really too difficult), but I can also recommend [`subdir` from the MATLAB File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15859-subdir--a-recursive-file-search), which utilizes the same input and output syntax as `dir`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? (Tested and run for my own purposes, so I know it works to the extent described in the comment lines)

```
function status =  rview(thedir)

yesdirs = rdir(thedir,'isdir');
% when numel(yesdirs) ==0 there are no directories; note that yesdirs does
% not include . or .. by design.
if numel(yesdirs),
    %assume no idiot every mixed files and directories in a given dir
    for j =1:numel(yesdirs),
        disp(sprintf('going to %s',yesdirs(j).name));
        eval(sprintf('cd ''%s'' ', yesdirs(j).name));
        thedir = sprintf('d%d',j);
        stat(j).(thedir) = rview('.');
        cd('..');
    end
else
    %no subdirectories.. worked our way to the bottom
    your_function_here() 
    %  indicator of where we were

    stat= ['did_' cd];
end

status = stat;
end
```

Comment: Apologies but I have changed it now. Now I start in a folder 'mainFolder' which contains all the folders that I need and just need to cycle through them, open them up separately and then pull out the files I need.

mainFolder = dir(fullfile('foldername'));

for k = 1:numel(mainFolder)
    subFolder = mainFolder(k);

this has the idea that it would loop through the folders and open each individual sub-folder, then go into my function and at the end of the function return back to the main folder